# PHP Search Results in table, order by name or highest price

Tags: php, sorting

I'm not very familiar with PHP so it would be amazing if someone could give me a hand on this. 
We are using Vik Rent Car WordPress plugin (a booking system for car rental). We have set 3 pricing types for customers to choose from, so after they've selected dates and see the search results with available cars, these 3 options show up. 
Now by default, the first and pre-selected option is the cheapest option, but we need this to be the other way around, so the first and pre-selected option should be the most expensive one. 
By coincidence, the name of the most expensive option starts with a "C" and the cheapest with an "Y", so if it could be sorted by name that would also be a solution. 
This is the snippet which i believe contains the code for showing the search results.
Is there anyone who could tell me how to insert a code to make these search results sorted by Price (descending) or by name (ascending).
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
    <div class="car_prices table-responsive">
        <span class="vrhword"><?php echo JText::_('VRPRICE'); ?></span>
        <table class="table">
        <?php
        $loopnum = 0;
        foreach ($tars as $k => $t) {
            $has_promotion = array_key_exists('promotion', $t) ? true : false;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="pid<?php echo $t['idprice']; ?>"<?php echo $has_promotion === true ? ' class="vrc-label-promo-price"' : ''; ?>>
                        <div class="vrc-showprc-priceinfo">
                            <span class="vrc-showprc-pricename"><?php echo VikRentCar::getPriceName($t['idprice'], $vrc_tn); ?></span>
                            <span class="vrc-showprc-pricecost">
                                <?php echo "<span class=\"vrc_currency\">".$currencysymb."</span> <span class=\"vrc_price\">".($tax_summary ? VikRentCar::numberFormat($t['cost']) : VikRentCar::numberFormat(VikRentCar::sayCostPlusIva($t['cost'], $t['idprice'])))."</span>"; ?>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    if (strlen($t['attrdata'])) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="vrc-showprc-priceattr">
                            <?php echo VikRentCar::getPriceAttr($t['idprice'], $vrc_tn).": ".$t['attrdata']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="priceid" id="pid<?php echo $t['idprice']; ?>" value="<?php echo $t['idprice']; ?>"<?php echo ($loopnum == 0 ? " checked=\"checked\"" : ""); ?>/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $loopnum++;
        }
        ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't specify the sort order in the query? It seems pointless to sort it twice.

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions, i just don't know how to do it myself and the support of the plugin hasn't been of any help. Does this code already contains a line where sort order is specified?

Comment: ^ no, your posted code is just dealing with the results from the query. You'd need to look at the bit of code that actually creates the query and passes the parameters to it.

Comment: Just noticed that the add-in you use is a paid-for product, why can't their support help you?

Comment: Thank you Droopsnoot, i will search and hire a php developer to do it for me as I don't now how to proceed. Thanks for your help. And yes I've asked for support but they replied "as you can read from our terms & conditions, we do not offer any kind of support service on code customizations, I'm sorry. All I can tell you is that you should edit the ordering of the rate plans in the "default.php" file of the view "showprc" through an override. ".